# How to use prepared statements (named parameters) on a php Class

Tags: php, class, pdo, prepared-statement, named-parameters

I want to know how to use named parameters in a prepared statement with pdo  class, so the call to pdo look something like following.

```php
$query = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE login = :login AND pww = :pww');
$query->execute(array('login' => $login, 'pww' => $pww));
```

And I want to integrate this on a class regardless of the number of parameters.

Currently, I have [this](http://pastebin.com/kKgSkaKt) code

```php
require_once 'constants.php';

class Mysql extends PDO {

    private $con;

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->con = parent::__construct(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            if ($this->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME) == DB_TYPE)
                $this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, TRUE);
            return $this->con;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function select($reqSelect) {
        try {
            $this->con = parent::beginTransaction();
            $result = parent::prepare($reqSelect);
            $result->execute();

            //$this->con = parent::commit();
            $this->con = parent::rollBack();
            return $result;
            $result->closeCursor();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function selectAll($reqSelect) {
        $result = parent::prepare($reqSelect);
        $result->execute();
        $resultat = $result->fetchAll();
        return $resultat;
        $result->closeCursor();
    }
}
```

And for parameters, I use somethings like ( which is wrong and vulnerable to injection )

```php
require_once 'classes/Mysql.class.php';
$mysql = new Mysql();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = '.$_GET['id'].' LIMIT 1';
$data = $mysql->select($sql);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question or problem.

Comment: +1 for trying to use PDO

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to pass sql query to a method that will parse string to get user input from `where` clause and replace it with `?`, prepare statement and bind grabbed user input?

Comment: @PLB: Yeah! something like that, i method that parse sql string and ( with maybe some additionnal method's parameters) whenever there's a ":someting" its a parameter, and bind it, regardless of the number of parameters.

Comment: im just hardcoding it, but the idea is http://pastebin.com/ViZfuwk0, and making it more flexible, regadless or the number of named parameters given.

Answer (score 1):

So it's seems that I have figured it out, the trick was adding an optional parameter to the function, you use it whenever you need to work with prepared statements (named parameters).
So the function is something like

```php
public function selectAll($reqSelect, $param = null) {
    $result = parent::prepare($reqSelect);
    //Check whether the parameter was passed or not
    if (is_null($param)) {
        $result->execute();
        $resultat = $result->fetchAll();
        return $resultat;
    } else {
        //Binding the parameters
        $result->execute($param);
        $resultat = $result->fetchAll();
        return $resultat;
    }
    $result->closeCursor();
}
```

And for applying it, it goes like

```php
//First param, the SQL. Here we have named parameters, so we need them to get bind
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE publish = :number';
//Second param, the parameters that will get bind with the named ones
$param = array(':number' => 1);

$query = $mysql->selectAll($sql, $param);

foreach ($query as $row) {
    extract($row);
    echo $title . '<br />';
}
```

I don't know if this, is considered the best practice, secured or even correct. if I'm mistaken feel free to correct me.